# How can I force a guide to snap pixels whilst being dragged?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mac

When I drag my mouse through a ruler to create a new guide, I want this guide to move pixel by pixel so that when I leave it, it will have snapped to a side of a pixel instead of staying in the middle.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Same problem been using zoom and snap and guides for 20 years, and really irritated that this level of software can't perform this basic task. Found zero solutions, actually had to open the image in PAINT to effect the correct placement. Seriously, this merits a refund! You've got to be kidding.

Answer (score 16):

You need to be at 500% zoom or higher and then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse Button</kbd> to have your guides snap to the pixel grid.

Otherwise, by default it'll snap to:

- every 2 pixels at greater than 100% zoom
- every 5 pixels at 100% zoom
- every 10 pixels at less than 100% zoom

However, if you set your grid to every pixel, then it should snap to the pixel at 100% zoom or greater, even if `Snap to`>`Grid` isn't enabled. At zooms less than 100%, you'll need `Snap to`>`Grid` as well as have the grid enabled.

But I usually just use the rectangular marquee to mark out the positions where I want my guides to snap to. This avoids having to zoom in or having to change my grid settings.

Comment: Nope, shift + move guide doesn't snap to the pixel grid... (Mountain Lion, Photoshop version 12.1 x64). Also tried combinations of keys and drag without any success.

Comment: Positioning a horizontal guide in CS6, if you are zoomed in too far it snaps to `Y: 0.0px`.  Zoom out a bit to get it to snap to pixels properly again.  Frustrating.

Comment: @user13722 had a similar problem but realized that i had to turn on snap

Comment: This only works if Snap is active.

Answer (score 3):

What definitively worked for me was the following in Adobe Photoshop CS6:

1. Go to your menu bar and click on `Edit` > `Preferences` > `Units & Rulers`.
2. Change Rulers's units to **Pixels**.
3. Now drag your guides while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

[image]

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Have you...

1. turned on snap to guides?
2. select a blank layer, so guides won't snap to anything else in the comp.
3. set your ruler measurement by right clicking on the ruler.
4. hold down shift + move your guide which snaps percisely to the ruler setting.

Also when you select View > New Guide and specify a vertical position does this snap correctly?

Sorry if this is duplicating previous suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold Shift while dragging., at least in Windows.

Comment: Hello, I did try it but it skips more than a pixel. Strange situation. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried zooming in?

Comment: Yes, zoomed in or out, it jumps 3 to 4 pixels. ;-)

Comment: It wouldn't have anything to do with what you've got set in your Preferences > Unit & Rulers or Guides, Grid & Slices

Comment: Wouldn't it? Why not?

Comment: Then I don't know. At least for me, in CS5 & W7 64bits, once I zoom in a bit, and holding shift, the guides go pixel by pixel :S Maybe it's other button for Mac.

Comment: I think I was misundsertandng your question, I thought you might be snapping to grid lines in pts. I've added another response.